# Combine Akka config with my config

Tags: scala, akka

I'm writing an Akka microkernel application, and would like to have it determine it's own host IP using `java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost.getHostAddress`.  If this call succeeds then I'd use the address for the property `akka.remote.netty.hostname`, but if not I'll fall back to a value in the `application.config`.

This was working ok with `System.setProperty("akka.remote.netty.hostname", addr)`, as demonstrated in the `SimpleClusterApp` in the [Akka docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2-M2/cluster/cluster-usage-scala.html).

The problem came when I wanted to first check if some other key had been set in the application.config.  For example, the following would fail to override the host address because (I think) the initial call to `ConfigFactory.load()` means that the `System.setProperty` which follows has no effect.

```
if(ConfigFactory.load().getBoolean("my-app.do-something")){
    //Do some stuff, then change the host address
    Try{
        java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost.getHostAddress
    } match {
        case Success(addr) => 
            System.setProperty("akka.remote.netty.hostname", addr)
        case Failure(_) => 
    }
}
```

Must I use a separate config file for configuring my own application, or is there another way to fix the above problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call

```
ConfigFactory.invalidateCaches()
```

after you set the property.  This is a good technique to remember for unit testing.

Alternatively, use a parsed config fragment and `fallbackTo` like:

```
def remoteConfig(hostname: String, port: Int, commonConfig: Config): Config = {
  val configStr = s"""
    akka.remote.netty.hostname = $hostname
    akka.remote.netty.port = $port
  """
  ConfigFactory.parseString(configStr).withFallback(commonConfig)
}

val baseConfig = ConfigFactory.load()
val akkaConfig = if (!baseConfig.getBoolean("my-app.do-something")) baseConfig
else
  Try(java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost.getHostAddress).
    map(remoteConfig(_, 0, baseConfig)).
    getOrElse(baseConfig) 

val system = ActorSystem("foo", akkaConfig)
```